# Prototype change original

Tags: javascript, prototype

I have a prototype function that changes Boolean `true` to `false` and visa versa.

```
Boolean.prototype.switch = function() {
    return this.toString() === 'false';
};
```

And currently I have to use the following to change the original value.

```
var a = true;
a = a.switch();
```

Is there a way I can change the original variable (`a`) without `a =`?  Meaning the script below run the same as above?

```
var a = true;
a.switch();
```

I am creating a quick game, and in the game there are 25 blocks which can have a value of on or off, or as I made it, `true` or `false`.  When you click the block it switches values.  While I was making the code to switch the values, I became a bit curious to if there is a way to remove `a =` and still change the value.

**Note** I am not asking for help with how to make this prototype function, I am asking if there is a way to change the value without a left hand side in an assignment

Comment: I think you should elaborate on why you want to do that.

Comment: @mhyst arguably it's "cheaper" to toggle the value of an existing object than to create a new one

Comment: @mhyst mainly I'm just curious, but I will edit my question to add details.

Comment: A better `switch` method would simple be `!this` instead of comparing Strings.

Comment: @PitaJ but that always returns `false`, I made the script to switch `true` to `false` and `false` to `true`.

Comment: Actually, that's a interesting behavior, since this is an object, you'd have to cast it to a primitive first. Maybe `this == false` instead?

Comment: Tip: A better name for this method would be `not`, and a better implementation would be `return !this.valueOf();`.

Comment: Are you aware that there is a difference between the primitive `boolean` type and an instance of the `Boolean` "class"? When you have `var a = true`, you only get a primitive boolean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not possible - `Boolean` objects are effectively immutable.

You cannot assign to `this` in a method, and nor does the `Boolean` object expose any method to change its own value that you might have called.

Comment: And in general it's a bad idea to extend the native prototype. An obvious exception would be to add polyfills for older browsers.

Comment: @andlrc why is it a bad idea?

Comment: @Jaketr00 There are tons of questions on the SE community, one is this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034180/why-is-extending-native-objects-a-bad-practice

Comment: in modern JS IMHO it's fine to extend native prototypes so long as it's done using `Object.defineProperty`.  There's plenty of other languages that encourage adding methods to standard classes and I don't see anything in JS that makes it special in that regard.  If you do it right you even get a runtime error if another library tries to implement the same method.

Comment: …and most of all, because `a` does not hold a Boolean object but rather a boolean value.

Comment: @Bergi yup, AFAICS in Chrome a `boolean` is a `[[PrimitiveType]]` that inherits from the `Boolean` prototype.

Comment: @Alnitak: primitives are no objects, so they can't inherit from anything. Only when they are cast to objects (e.g. as a `this` value or when a property is accessed on them), they produce `Boolean` instances.

Comment: @Bergi ah, it was the `this` thing, then - I tried `Boolean.prototype.show = function() { console.log(this) }` and that showed `[[PrimitiveType]]` but I misread that as the type (which as actually `Boolean`) rather than just the wrapped primitive.

Comment: @andlrc—the discussion here on "native" prototypes should be about [**built–in**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-built-in-object) prototypes. There are no "native" objects in ECMAScript 2015.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement your own object with the desired behaviour, however be careful of strict equality:

```js
// Constructor
function MyBool(trueOrFalse) {
  this.value = !!trueOrFalse;
}

// Switch method
MyBool.prototype.switch = function() {
  this.value = !this.value;
}

// Custom valueOf and toString methods to act like a primitive
MyBool.prototype.valueOf = function() {
  return this.value;
}

MyBool.prototype.toString = function() {
  return '' + this.value;
}

// Initialise as false
var a = new MyBool(false);
document.write('a is currently: ' + a);
 
// Switch to true
a.switch()
document.write('<br>a is now: ' + a);

// Use in expression
document.write('<br>a == true? : ' + (a == true)) 
document.write('<br>a === true? : ' + (a === true)) // Ooops!
document.write('<br>!!a === true? : ' + (!!a === true)) // Work around
document.write('<br>in contional : ' + (a? 'true'  : 'false'))
```